# Refresh div every few minutes - rails

Tags: javascript, refresh

I have part of a page that needs to be refreshed every few minutes, I've done this before in php and adjusted it to the following for rails:

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
       setInterval(function() {
        $("#welcome2").load("floor7.haml #welcome2");
    }, 500);
  });
```

But this won't work in my rails application, I'm not sure if i'm putting the correct file path in?

I get this: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

**Update**

```
<body style="background: #000; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS'; overflow-x: hidden; margin:0;">
<script>
  //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
             setInterval(function() {
              $("#welcome2").load("/screen/floor7.haml #welcome2");
          }, 500);
    });
  //]]>
</script>
<div id='welcome2'>
  <span>Welcome</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to include the code you are trying to use in your rails app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
           setInterval(function() {
            $("#refresh").load("welcome.php #refresh");
        }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: That was my example of the code i used with my php file, I've used your suggestion and get this `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: have u included jquery library?

Comment: well.. I think so, I've used jquery for other things, and they work!

Comment: not really, because it's in rails there are like 5 different files that make up the page.

Comment: ok...after the page is rendered in browser....click view source and copy paste the html code..no need of all 5 files

Comment: I've updated my question with the code I think you'd need to look at

Comment: dats not the complete code i guess?are u building up html code dynamically in ruby?And the jquery is not referred any where.

Comment: where it says "welcome" that's dynamic and could change when the div is refreshed.

Comment: I understand what you meant now, I'd included that in my other layouts but not this one! It works now, Thank you so much!